# Firefox addon: TypeError: getBrowserForTab(...) is undefined

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

While attaching an object to `window` of the active tab in `main.js`, I get following error:

```
 Message: TypeError: getBrowserForTab(...) is undefined
```

Here is the code that I've used to attach the object:

```
var { getTabs, getTabContentWindow } = require('sdk/tabs/utils');
tabs.on('load', function(tab) {
    var window = getTabContentWindow(tab);    
    window.myObject = {
     data: "sample"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the `tabs.on('load', function(tab) {})` is a part of the high-level API, whereas `getTabContentWindow` from `require('sdk/tabs/utils')` works on low-level XUL tabs. Use `viewFor` from `sdk/view/core` to transform:

```
var { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
var window = getTabContentWindow(viewFor(tab))
```

Comment: I was struggling with the same problem as the poster.  For future reference, where in the Mozilla's SDK website is that documented?